# Empty page when creating a Firefox session

Tags: session, selenium, firefox, intern

I am running functional test with Selenium server standalone. Through this link http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub , I can create session. I choose to create a Firefox session but the page I got is empty, is it normal? I am following Intern tutorial. Am I not supposed to have the index.html page displayed?

could someone enlighted this issue for me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Selenium will always open an empty page. With the get method of your driver you can navigate to a page you want. ie. in python driver.get('http:// stackoverflow.com') (i've added a space because otherwise a hyperlink would be shown instead of the url)

Comment: Thank you @RemcoV for your answer, I did not know. So how can I display the page that I want to test? All my tests are failed, I am having this message 'Error: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444'
 So how can I fixed it?

Comment: @mkinf Could you add some of your code to your question?

Comment: @mkinf that error means that your intern runner could not find a local selenium instance. did you stop your server?

Comment: @erikdstock I did not stop my server. I launched the selenium server and it was written "Selenium Server is up and running" .